Does anyone know how to get Magento 2 installed on a MacBook I just want it to be local with docker and NginX
I need to install Magento2 on a MacBook with docker and NginX but all the tutorials won't work can anyone help me? I have nothing installed on my MacBook it is brand new

Use this setup on mac https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento.
Use phpstorm like ide.
Use docker.
Let me no if the guide is complete.

Yes it worked thanks
